# Get JMS Destination From wmq using spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am consuming messages from IBM Mq using message driven channel adapter (Spring Integration) . JMS Destination property in the message is coming as null. Could someone tell me how to get queue name in header for messages consumed using wmq.
JMS Destination property is coming for messages consumed from apache Active mq but not for IBM MQ.

Comment: @JoshMc solution isnt available over there too.

Comment: The fact that you didn't get a answer you like to the first question does not mean you should ask the same duplicate question.  You should edit your prior question if you think it is unclear.

Comment: Yeah. Agreed...!!

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` has the code like this:

```
 try {
        Destination destination = jmsMessage.getJMSDestination();
        if (destination != null) {
            headers.put(JmsHeaders.DESTINATION, destination);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        this.logger.info("failed to read JMSDestination property, skipping", ex);
    }
```

So, if IBM Mq doesn't provide that property value, we really won't have a `JmsHeaders.DESTINATION` header on the matter.

I suggest you to investigate all the headers you get after consuming and see what one may have a required destination for you.

Otherwise you always can extend `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` and implement your own logic in the overridden `toHeaders()` method.

Comment: I have tried jmsMessage.getJMSDestination() which is returning null as well. I have inspected all the headers which doesn't have queue information.

Comment: Right. That's what I'm explaining why you don't get the value in the `JmsHeaders.DESTINATION` and I suggest you the way to go. What am I missing, please?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Does extending DefaultJmsHeaderMapper can solve my issue? Can i get my queue name in the overridden toHeaders() method?

Comment: Do you not know by context what queue you are reading from?  You had to specify the queue name to open it and read messages.

Comment: I would be consuming a lot queues and passing to a common channel. I would  not be knowing the queue name  in my channel.

Comment: You need to consult with IBM to determine in what `JmsMessage` property they populate a `Destination`. And then use that property in the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` extension, e.g. call `super.toHeaders()`, check if `JmsHeaders.DESTINATION` header is null and populate a destination from that IBM property. Does it make sense to you?